# Unsure if it is valid to define a real number b less than abs(x-a) if x is a variable

Tags: limits, inequality, real-numbers, epsilon-delta

I am currently working through some questions from my course to do with proving continuity. In one question I have to go through and spot the error in a given proof. In one line there is defined a fixed real number $b$ where $0\lt b \lt \lvert x-a \rvert$ where $a$ is a given real number and $0 \lt \lvert x-a \rvert \lt \delta$ holds. I thought this might be an illegitimate definition, because $x$ is a variable and so its value isn't fixed and hence $b$'s value wouldn't be fixed either. Is this correct?

Comment: You are certainly correct that there is no real number $b$ which satisfies those inequalities for all $x$ (assuming $a$ is fixed). Just take $x=a+\frac b2$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: There certainly is a problem with quantifying over $x$ here. Can you please state the problem in its entirety so that people can take guess at how $x$ is supposed to be quantified?